# Multiple Button with one function but different functionalities

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a table using div tag. In total there are 9 rows each row has three columns the third column of each row is a button the first and second column shows the product name and price respectively. Now, as i said, each row contain a button,what i want is that after we click the button the method must add the quantity of the product of which button is clicked. suppose hit the button of the product "Pepsi" i want that the method should display below the table "Pepsi quantity in cart = 1". If we again hit the buy button adjacent to product pepsi the 1 changes to 2. same things must happen to other products.

according to my code the item.name will be always "Dairy Milk".

```js
var countP1 = 0;
var p1 = {
  "Name": "Pepsi",
  "Price": 15
};
var p2 = {
  "Name": "coke",
  "Price": 10
};
var p3 = {
  "Name": "Mirinda",
  "Price": 20
};
var p4 = {
  "Name": "Sprite",
  "Price": 16
};
var p5 = {
  "Name": "Minute Maid",
  "Price": 25
};
var p6 = {
  "Name": "5star",
  "Price": 10
};
var p7 = {
  "Name": "Kitkat",
  "Price": 15
};
var p8 = {
  "Name": "perk",
  "Price": 8
};
var p9 = {
  "Name": "Dairy Milk",
  "Price": 30
};
var arr = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9];
var s1 = "<div class = 'divHead'>" + "Name" + "</div>";
var s2 = "<div class = 'divHead'>" + "Price" + "</div>";
var s3 = "<div class = 'divHead'>" + "Buy" + "</div>";
var str = s1 + s2 + s3;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var item = arr[i];
  var name = "<div class = 'divCell'>" + item.Name + "</div>";
  var price = "<div class = 'divCell'>" + item.Price + "</div>";
  var buy = "<div class = 'divCell'>" + "<button onclick='buyMat()' > "+" Buy "+" < /button>"+"</div > ";;
  var row = "<div class = 'divRow'>" + name + price + buy + "</div>";
  str = str + row;
}
document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML = str;

function buyMat() {
  console.log(countP1);
  console.log(item.Name);
  if (item.Name == "Pepsi") {
    countP1 += 1;

    document.getElementById("id2").innerHTML = item.name + " , quaantity in cart = "+countP1;
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="id1"></div>
<div class='divCart' id="id2">Cart is Empty!</div>
```

what my output should like be:
[image: what my output should like be]

Comment: Rahul, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56987554/revisions and edit if you need other changes. I just removed some new lines to get the code you provided up and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rahul, I corrected few lines in your code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="section8.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id = "id1"></div>
<div class = 'divCart' id = "id2">Cart is Empty!</div>
</body>
<script>
var countP1 = 0;    
var p1 = {"Name":"Pepsi","Price":15};
var p2 = {"Name":"coke","Price":10};
var p3 = {"Name":"Mirinda","Price":20};
var p4 = {"Name":"Sprite","Price":16};
var p5 = {"Name":"Minute Maid","Price":25};
var p6 = {"Name":"5star","Price":10};
var p7 = {"Name":"Kitkat","Price":15};
var p8 = {"Name":"perk","Price":8};
var p9 = {"Name":"Dairy Milk","Price":30};
var arr = [p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9];
var s1 = "<div class = 'divHead'>"+"Name"+"</div>";
var s2 = "<div class = 'divHead'>"+ "Price"+"</div>";
var s3 = "<div class = 'divHead'>"+"Buy"+"</div>";
var str = s1+s2+s3;
for(var i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
    var item = arr[i];
    var name = "<div class = 'divCell'>"+item.Name+"</div>";
    var price = "<div class = 'divCell'>"+item.Price+"</div>";
    var buy ="<div class = 'divCell'>"+'<button onclick = "buyMat('+i+')">'+"Buy"+"</button>"+"</div>";;
    var row = "<div class = 'divRow'>"+name+price+buy+"</div>";
    str = str + row;
}
document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML = str;

function buyMat(n){
    console.log(countP1);
    console.log(arr[n].Name);
    if(arr[n].Name == "Pepsi"){
        countP1+=1;

        document.getElementById("id2").innerHTML = arr[n].name +" , quaantity in cart = "+countP1;
        }

}

</script>
```

var arr contains the data so need to check in that variable for selected item and also need to pass the item value through the click function.

Comment: now the code is updating the "id2". could u pls tell me a way so that if i click another prdoucts buy button it get append to the previous one.. and if i click the previous product`s buy button it should update on the same button rather than appending on a new line @Prashant

Comment: create counters for all the products. Based on clicked item value increase the counter value for that product. To display the data create tag fields for all the products and update the values according to the products. Initially make tag fields hidden then according to products show them @Rahul